# Decomposition of r square into fixed and random effect in a GAMM (mgcv)

Tags: r-squared, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gamm4

for a paper I estimated a generalized additive model using R's mgcv. One reviewer now asks whether it would be possible to report a marginal and conditional r square instead of a global r square to "to quantify how much variance was due to interindividual differences (random effects) and how much is due to fixed effects".

I saw that this is possible in a GLMM but did not find a way to do it in a GAMM (estimated with the bam-function).

Does anybody have an idea? I should mentioned that the output variable was a proportion and I estimated the model with the betar family (and link=logit).

Comment: It's possible but via variance components. I've been working on this in my {gratia}  but haven't finished the implementation yet. Other packages, like {insight} provide the necessary computations for a range of models but not GAMs, hence my working on it in {gratia}. I haven't pushed any of these changes to GitHub yet, but I will see about reminding myself of the details and put them in an answer. In the meantime, {insight} has the details they just need to be applied to the GAM representation of a GLMM